# Colon remap not working for registers(?)

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, register

I have my colon key remapped to switch with semicolon using both `nnoremap` and `vnoremap`. This works fine except when I want to repeat the last command line with `@:`.

Unfortunately, the remapping does not work when doing this, so I have to type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>

Why is the remapping not working in this context?

Comment: Well, just keep the shift key held down when you hit the other keys. IMO that's easier than typing `@;` If not just remap `@;` .

Answer (score 2):

You have to remap `@:` as well:

```
nnoremap @; @:
```

You might as well remap `q:` while you're at it:

```
nnoremap q; q:
```

Comment: What does 'q:' do? I though q was unbound.

Comment: `q:` opens the command-line window, where the command line can be edited just like editing text in any window.  See [`:help cmdline-window`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-window), [`:help q:`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q:) and [`:help E119`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E199) for details.

Comment: @TylerDurden `q` is not unbound.  It's a prefix for recording macros and opening command line editing.

Comment: This web page says it is unbound: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html

Comment: It also says that `v`, `V`, and `K` are unbound.  Maybe it's talking about original vi?  Read `:help normal-index`, `:help insert-index`, and `:help visual-index` if you want to see all of the keys.